# Toast notification doesn't works

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I wrote some code, that check availability of internet connection, but it doesn't work.

I don't see any toast notifications. I wrote all permissions in manifest file.

What's wrong in this code?

```
namespace MurakamiKiev

[Activity(Label = "Murakami",MainLauncher = true,Icon = "@drawable/logo", Theme = "@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar", ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
        ImageButton next = FindViewById<ImageButton> (Resource.Id.nextButton);
        ImageButton previous = FindViewById<ImageButton> (Resource.Id.previousButton);
        ImageButton home = FindViewById<ImageButton> (Resource.Id.homeButton);
        ImageButton cart = FindViewById<ImageButton> (Resource.Id.cartButton);
        Button sushi = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.sushiButton);
        Button sets = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.setsbutton);
        //Button rolli = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.rollibutton);
        ImageButton menu = FindViewById<ImageButton> (Resource.Id.menuButton);

        //Otslezivaem click po knopke 'next' i perehodim dalshe
        /*rolli.Click += delegate
        {
            var intent139 = new Intent(this, typeof(RolliActivity));
            StartActivity(intent139);

        };*/
        sets.Click += delegate {
            var intent121 = new Intent (this, typeof(SetsActivity));
            StartActivity (intent121);

        };
        sushi.Click += delegate {
            var intent24 = new Intent (this, typeof(SushiActivity));
            StartActivity (intent24);

        };
        next.Click += delegate {
            var intent = new Intent (this, typeof(MenuActivity));
            StartActivity (intent);
        };
        //Otlezivaem click po knopke 'Korzina' i perehodim v nee
        cart.Click += delegate {
            var intent2 = new Intent (this, typeof(CartActivity));
            StartActivity (intent2);
        };
        menu.Click += delegate {
            var intent39 = new Intent (this, typeof(MenuTopActivity));
            StartActivity (intent39);

        };
    }

    public void CheckNetwork()
    {
        var connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)GetSystemService(ConnectivityService);

        var activeConnection = connectivityManager.ActiveNetworkInfo;

        if ((activeConnection != null) && activeConnection.IsConnected)
        {
            Toast.MakeText (this, "OK", ToastLength.Short).Show ();
        } 

        else 
        {
            Toast.MakeText (this, "Connect to the wi-fi", ToastLength.Short).Show ();
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: where u call the checkNetwork method

Comment: In Main Activity @arun

Comment: There is no sign of calling checkNetwork in the above code.

Comment: public void CheckNetwork()
    {
        var connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)GetSystemService(ConnectivityService);

        var activeConnection = connectivityManager.ActiveNetworkInfo;

        if ((activeConnection != null) && activeConnection.IsConnected)
        {
            Toast.MakeText (this, "OK", ToastLength.Short).Show ();
        } 

        else 
        {
            Toast.MakeText (this, "Connect to the wi-fi", ToastLength.Short).Show ();
        }       
    }
}

@arun

Comment: you didn't call CheckNetwork();  some where on your oncreate method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What's wrong in this code?

You did not call your method anywhere, so it will never show you the `Toast`, because the method is **NEVER** called.

> How to solve it?

For example if you want to checkconnection when you launch the `Activity` just add this method as follows :

```
 protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate (bundle);

    // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
    SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
    ImageButton next = FindViewById<ImageButton> (Resource.Id.nextButton);
    ImageButton previous = FindViewById<ImageButton> (Resource.Id.previousButton);
    ImageButton home = FindViewById<ImageButton> (Resource.Id.homeButton);
    ImageButton cart = FindViewById<ImageButton> (Resource.Id.cartButton);
    Button sushi = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.sushiButton);
    Button sets = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.setsbutton);
    //Button rolli = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.rollibutton);
    ImageButton menu = FindViewById<ImageButton> (Resource.Id.menuButton);


    CheckNetwork(); //Here you'll ask if you have connection or not and Toast will show
```

Comment: No problem, it happens happy coding ;)

Comment: **Always** debug your app and each function you think is not working correctly with breakpoints, always by starting from the last not expecting result to the first